# Opencart 3.x version: cannot remove "powered by"

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I cannot remove the "powered by opencart" on the footer in version 3.x. The new files are all twigg files and I don't know where or how to do it.
Any help on the path and configuration, please.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 5):

The file `catalog/language/en-gb/common/footer.php` has

`$_['text_powered']      = 'Powered By <a href="http://www.opencart.com">OpenCart</a><br /> %s &copy; %s';`

change this to

`$_['text_powered']      = '';`